# laravel does not upload images

Tags: php, html, laravel

I have had problems with laravel for days
since I can not upload images to the registration form that corresponds to the logo
already try to validate the logo field in different ways but laravel does not accept them
laravel always responds that the image I'm trying to upload is not an image
here my controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use App\Role;
use App\Actserv;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
use Webcraft\Random\RandomFacade;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{

use RegistersUsers;

/**
 * Where to redirect users after registration.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $redirectTo = '/home';

/**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest');
}

/**
 * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
 */
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        //'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|string|email|min:6|max:128|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|string||min:6|max:128|confirmed',
        'nombre_empresa' => 'required|string|unique:users|min:1|max:255',
        'pais' => 'required|string|not_in:Opción no seleccionada|max:128',
        'tipo' => 'required|string|not_in:Opción no seleccionada|max:128',
        'ciudad' => 'required|string|min:1|max:200',
        'direccion' => 'required|string|min:1|max:255',
        'telefono' => 'nullable|numeric',
        'celular_e' => 'required|unique:users|numeric',
        'postal' => 'nullable|string|min:1|max:128',
        'nit' => 'nullable|unique:users|numeric|min:1',
        'web' => 'nullable|string|min:1|max:255',
        'facebook' => 'nullable|string|min:1|max:255',
        'oferta' => 'required|string|min:1|max:255',
        'demanda' => 'required|string|min:1|max:255',
        'nombre_r' => 'required|string|min:1|max:128',
        'ci' => 'required|unique:users|numeric',
        'email_r' => 'required|unique:users|string|email|min:1|max:128',
        'cargo' => 'required|string|min:1|max:128',
        'celular_r' => 'required|numeric|unique:users',
        //--------------------------------------------
        //field that validates the logo---------------
        'logo' => 'nullable|image|mimes:jpg,bmp,png',
        //--------------------------------------------
        'actv'  => 'required|array|min:1',
        'actv.0'  => 'required|string|not_in:Opción no seleccionada|max:255',
        'actv.1'  => 'string|max:255',
        'actv.2'  => 'string|max:255',

        'srv' => 'required|array|min:1',
        'srv.0' => 'required|string|not_in:Opción no seleccionada|max:255',
        'srv.1' => 'string|max:255',
        'srv.2' => 'string|max:255', 
    ]);    
}


/**
 * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return \App\User
 */


protected function create(array $data)
{

    $cod = RandomFacade::generateString(6, '1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'); //se genera un unico codigo por cada usuario registrado
    $user = User::create([
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        'nombre_empresa' => $data['nombre_empresa'],
        'pais' => $data['pais'],
        'tipo' => $data['tipo'],
        'ciudad' => $data['ciudad'],
        'direccion' => $data['direccion'],
        'telefono' => $data['telefono'],
        'celular_e' => $data['celular_e'],
        'postal' => $data['postal'],
        'nit' => $data['nit'],
        'web' => $data['web'],
        'facebook' => $data['facebook'],
        'oferta' => $data['oferta'],
        'demanda' => $data['demanda'],
        'nombre_r' => $data['nombre_r'],
        'ci' => $data['ci'],
        'email_r' => $data['email_r'],
        'cargo' => $data['cargo'],
        'celular_r' => $data['celular_r'],
        'estado' => '0', //indica si el usuario esta activo(1) o inactivo(0)
        'tipo_user' => 'user',//indica que tipo de usuario es user=usuario normal admin=usuario administrador local=usuario designado por el admin
        'codigo' => $cod,
    ]);

    $actividad = $data['actv'];
    $servicios = $data['srv'];


    $actserv = Actserv::create([
        'emp_id' => $user->id,
        'actividad' => $actividad[0],
        'servicios' => $servicios[0],
    ]);
    $actserv = Actserv::create([
            'emp_id' => $user->id,
            'actividad' => $actividad[1],
            'servicios' => $servicios[1],
    ]);
    $actserv = Actserv::create([
        'emp_id' => $user->id,
        'actividad' => $actividad[2],
        'servicios' => $servicios[2],
    ]);

    $user
    ->roles()
    ->attach(Role::where('name', 'user')->first());

    return $user;   
}
}
```

and this is in the registration form:

```
 <form id="needs-validation" novalidate method="post" enctype=”multipart/form-data”>
 ...
   <label for="logo">Logo</label>
   <input type="file" class="form-control-file"  name="logo" id="logo">
 ...
 </form>
```

and I have this error when I try to upload an image

```
logo must be an image.
logo must be a file with format: jpeg, bmp, png.
```

What could be the error?
Thank you

Comment: How certain are you that you're uploading an actual image, and not something like a PDF?

Comment: because I'm uploading images that I verify with my eyes :<

Comment: show us the rest of the controller

Comment: I already published the rest of my controller

Comment: try adding the format `jpg` to the list.

Comment: try removing the `image` form the rules

Comment: Did you have tried image rule only?! i.e `nullable|image' only. Or do you have tried to change the image that you are trying to upload? @jhoss

Comment: yes, try that too but it did not work

Answer (score 0):

First, look your " on enctype they are different.  Second remove image from rules and try dd($data['image']); If there is different data try check form for another input type with name logo maybe its overwrited by something.